# synchronously show and hide controls in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 app I want to show a message before loading some items from database. After loading I want to hide the message again.

for examle my XAMLcode is like this:

```
<Grid Name="layoutRoot">
    <Button Content="load more..." 
            Click="loadmore_clicked"/>

    <TextBlock Name="loadingMessage"
               Visibility="Collapsed"
               Text="loading..." />

    <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="10"
                           Text="{Binding name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

and in my c# code I am trying something like this:

```
private void loadmore_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    LoadMoreItemsForLongList(); // loading more items for the LongListSelector's ItemSource
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

The "loadingMessage" TextBlock never been shown. For testing I put Thread.Sleep() in the LoadMoreItemsForLongList() function. But it didn't work either.

My goal is to show a "loadingMessage" TextBlock before start loading more data to the LongListSelector and hide the "loadingMessage" TextBlock after finishing load of more data. How can I do that? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that LoadMoreItemsForLongList is a blocking method. When visibility of the loadingMessage is set, it's visual apprearance won't get updated until control goes of the loadmore_clicked (which is running in UI thread) and UI can show the loadingMessage, but before that, it's Visibility set to Collapsed.

You run the LoadMoreItemsForLongList in another thread:

```
private void loadmore_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Task.Run( () => 
         LoadMoreItemsForLongList() // loading more items for the LongListSelector's ItemSource
    ).ContinueWith( () =>   
         loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    );
}
```

But you need to be aware that all UI interactions in the LoadMoreItemsForLongList need to done in UI Thread. You may use Dispatcher:

```
void LoadMoreItemsForLongList() {
     // Load list from DB
     CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.Current.RunAsync(
         CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
         this.lstItems.ItemsSouce = ...;
     });
}
```

But if you follow [async design patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464924.aspx) and define LoadMoreItemsForLongList async, you can do this instead:

```
private async void loadmore_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await LoadMoreItemsForLongListAsync();
    loadingMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

This is the prefered way. and again, you still need to perfom UI actions of LoadMoreItemsForLongListAsync in UI thread.

Comment: The function LoadMoreItemsForLongList() inside Task.Run() never be called!

Comment: It should get called if the Task.Run line executes. Did you set a breakpoint at start of the LoadMoreItemsForLongList method?